# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run automation tests using selenium grid. I have configured hub and node as  `java -jar :D\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub.`

```
 java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="D:\geckodriver.exe" -jar D:\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser browserName=Firefox,maxInstances=5
```

since my gecko driver and selenium jar is in "D" drive.

But when I am trying to run test from eclipse IDE, it throws an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Command duration or timeout: 96 milliseconds  I am unable to identify  where It is going wrong??
```

I am using firefox 47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know how to solve this issue.
Actually it is the issue with Firefox Browser version.

Selenium 3.4.0 works best with 
geckodriver 0.16
 Firefox 52.0.3 and onward.

And I then configured node as

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="D:\geckodriver.exe" -jar D:\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser "browserName=Firefox,version=53.0,maxInstances=5"
```

Now it is working.